# Is $ \frac{x+y}{x^3 y^3 - x^3 y - x y^3 + 2 xy + 1} $ a formal group law?

Tags: rational-functions, associativity, symmetric-functions, formal-groups

Is $ \frac{x+y}{x^3 y^3 - x^3 y - x y^3 + 2 xy + 1} $ a formal group law on the interval $[-1,1]$ ?

It is a lot of work to check on associativity imo.

Maybe there is a shortcut around checking associativity ? Or a way to check it faster ?

Is there an easy algoritm to check if a symmetric rational function $f(x,y)$ is a formal group law ?

Comment: Is this not something a computer algebra system could check quickly?

Comment: Let $\,x=y=1/2,z=-1/2.\,$ Then $\,f(x,f(y,z))=1/2 \ne f(f(x,y),z).$

Comment: Ok, after having given a computer time on it (including giving a computer over 20 minutes to simplify $f(x,f(y,z))$ and $f(f(x,y),z)$ as best it can and 5 more to find examples like Somos's in an automated way), I can say that "no", using a computer (in a naive way) is *not* a fast way to check something like this. But it at least helped me *manually* try a random-ish point like Somos did to verify that this one isn't a formal group law.

Comment: Was The testing with $1/2,1/2,-1/2$ a wild guess or are those values computed ? Im unaware of a way to check this fast with a simple math program. —- Thank you for the “ no-answer “ but ofcourse many questions remain for me ...  My intention is not just to be able to decide for a single case , but for a family of rationals ... for instance : what rational functions with denom of degree 3 are a formal group law on $[-1,1]$  ?? Thanks

Comment: I’m not sure how it makes sense to speak of a “formal group on $[-1,1]$”. Ordinarily one does not speak of a formal group on a set, but a formal group defined over a ring. Did you mean, maybe, a “local group”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remembered that [sometimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Understatement) mathematicians do work that goes beyond what naive manipulations can do (even with a computer), and so I decided to search online for `rational formal group law`, and found a lot of good information.

Your question was answered very well in the mid 70's by Robert Bismuth in Corollary 2.5.4 of [his Masters thesis](http://hdl.handle.net/11375/9845): The *only* rational (one-dimensional) formal group laws over a field are those of the form $\boxed{F(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y+axy}{1+bxy}}$.

In particular, ***no*** rational functions with denominator of degree 3 are formal group laws.

That said, the proof in that thesis is long and somewhat hard to read. A much tidier proof for fields of characteristic zero is given in the 1991 paper "[Rational formal group laws](https://msp.org/pjm/1991/147-1/p02.xhtml)" by Robert Coleman and Francis Oisin McGuinness. More broadly, a (less explicit) characterization of *algebraic* formal group laws was done in Coleman's 1986 paper [One-dimensional algebraic formal groups](https://msp.org/pjm/1986/122-1/p03.xhtml).

All of this is summarized and presented with more context in [MSE's very own Alex Walker](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12084/awwalker)'s excellent blog post, [Formal Groups and Where to Find Them](https://awwalker.com/2017/02/05/formal-groups-and-where-to-find-them/).

Comment: Thank you. But I suggest writing more yourself because mainly you give links. Also because links can die.

Comment: @mick I'd be happy to, but I'm not sure what more you would like me to write. The individual links may die (though the handle.net link to the Masters thesis is less likely to die than most), but the papers I reference will always be found in libraries. Reproducing a significant portion of the proofs would feel like plagiarism, and if you would like a significant portion of Alex Walker's blog post reproduced on MSE (with the new license that would imply), I'd feel more comfortable if one of us asked him to do so himself.

Comment: Ok i accepted :)